# Why can't I call private shared methods from a public shared method in vb.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
    private shared default_ = "DEFAULT"

    public shared function bar(val as object) as string
        if val is Nothing then return _default

        return getBar(val)
    end function

    private shared function getBar(val as string) as string
        return formatString(val)
    end function

    private shared function getBar(val as System.Int32) as string
        return formatInt(val)
    end function
end class
```

formatString and FormatInt being public shared methods.
When I call Foo.bar, I get a MissingMemberException:

```
System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'getBar' on type 'Foo' not found.
```

It works, when I make getBar methods public, but I don't want to expose these unneccessarily. Why I can't call private shared methods from a public one in the same class is over my head.

I'm using .net framework 4.0 in a web application.

Comment: It feels strange looking at VB code where nearly everything starts with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @BoltClock - almost like the VB wants to become C#, or vice veras? :)

Comment: Well, the best thing about VB.Net is, I don't have to obey M$ coding style... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your public method takes an object as parameter and your private methods are taking string/integer. So the runtime does not know which overloaded method it should use.

If you make all overloaded methods `public`, the code only would compile if you have [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Off. Then on runtime no exception migth be thrown because the actual type of the object will be detected via late-binding(or even silently casted to a matching type, f.e. from `date` to `string`). But nevertheless, avoid [late binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with `Option Strict On` and use VB.NET as what it is supposed to be: a **strong typed language**.

The **Main-Reason** why your code throws a `MissingMemberException` with `Option Strict Off` and private methods is:

- If you are attempting to access members on a late-bound object variable, make sure it is declared Public(Protected , Friend, and Private variables [cannot be late-bound in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xdkcxy.aspx))

You could check the type of `val`, cast the object to this type and then pass that parameter to the correct method. For example:

```
Public Overloads Shared Function bar(ByVal val As Object) As String
      If val Is Nothing Then Return default_

      If TypeOf val Is String Then
          Return getBar(CStr(val))
      ElseIf TypeOf val Is Int32 Then
          Return getBar(CInt(val))
      Else
          Return default_
      End If
End Function
```

---

**Another point**: if you plan to create an Extension-Method that takes an object, [forget it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/01/24/extension-methods-and-late-binding-extension-methods-part-4.aspx):

> Mainly, we do not allow extension methods to be called off of any
>   expression that is statically typed as "Object". This was necessary to prevent any > existing late bound code you may have written from being broken by extension methods

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx (look for MissingMemberException)

Comment: I thought I was using strict, because I use it in the @Page directive, but this obviously doesn't propagate to the App_Code directory.

Comment: The first method you describe is exactly what I had before, but then I must check for Int32, Int64, Byte etc. with 20 case options... ugly.

Comment: @gpinkas: If you anyway overload this method for every type, you could simply make these functions public. On that way you don't need to type-check the object because always the correct one is called.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the detailed answer, but I still don't get why there is a difference when the getBar method is private/public.

Comment: @Tim: overloading the function itself is problematic, because I can't provide an overload for Object. But I need this also as fallback to the default value.

Comment: @gpinkas: edited my answer according the public/private issue.

Comment: Thanks Tim, so the problem is (other than the typing issue), that the RUNTIME environment cannot access the private member of the class, yes?

Comment: @gpinkas: Because i'm almost never using latebound it took some time to find the concret reason for your MissingMemberException. Have  a look at my answer(at "Main-Reason").

Comment: Ah, thanks for digging that up! And thanks for the useful explanation on top of that.